# PHP register form was working and now doesnt work after i've made no changes

Tags: php, registration

my registration no longer works, but i havent made any changes to it, why would this be? the only change i made was going into the database and change to id of 1 user and deleting 2 others.  here is my code:

```
include 'scripts/global.php';

// Register attempt  
if(isset($_POST['registerSubmit']) && $_POST['registerSubmit'] == 'true'){
$username = trim($_POST['username']);  
$email = trim($_POST['email']);  
$password = trim($_POST['password']);  
$confirmPassword    = trim($_POST['confirmPassword']);  

if(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email))  
    $errors['email'] = 'Your email address is invalid.';  

if(strlen($password) < 6)  
    $errors['password'] = 'Your password must be greater than 6 characters.';  

if($password != $confirmPassword)  
    $errors['confirmPassword'] = 'Your passwords did not match.';  

// Check to see if we have a user registered with this email address already  
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . '" LIMIT 1';  
$result = mysql_query($query);  
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)  
    $errors['email'] = 'This email address already exists.';

//Check if username is already taken
     $queryuser = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . '" LIMIT 1';  
$result = mysql_query($queryuser);  
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)  
    $errors['username'] = 'This username is already taken.';



if(!$errors){  
    $queryFinal = 'INSERT INTO users SET email = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . '", 
                                                                    password = MD5("' . mysql_real_escape_string($password) . '"), 
                                                                    date_registered = "' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '",
                                                                    username = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . '"';

    if(mysql_query($queryFinal)){  
        $success['register'] = 'Thank you for registering. You can now log in on the right.';  
    }else{  
        $errors['register'] = 'There was a problem registering you. Please check your details and try again.';  
    }  
}  

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Nobody knows what "doesn't work" is supposed to mean.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: it is running the last else statement so that it is displaying (my echo is  further down in the page), that the $errors['register'] occurred and not a successful register, so its telling me that mysql_query($queryFinal)) is not working

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it worked or what changed. But as far as I know, you cannot use the double quotes in queries around variable data like you have them here:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . '" LIMIT 1';
```

It should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "' LIMIT 1";
```

Same with your other query's. What would also help if you had some error's being displayed if something is awry:

```
$result = mysql_query($queryuser) or trigger_error('SQL Error on User Query: ' . mysql_error());
```

Which should also tell you what the error is / was. And this can be turned off to the end user easily with `display_errors` being set to off since it uses the `trigger_error`.

Comment: thanks, this worked, but for some reason, only if i did it to my bottom 4 in the last query and not the other queries, THANKS!